# Getting XPath selector to output text of parent and child element

Tags: xpath

I have a HTML tag like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
      <h1>This is a <b>xyz</b> test</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I do `hxs.select('/html/body/h1/text()').extract()` the output would be `This is a test`. How should I specify the XPath such that the output is `This is a xyz test`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do `/html/body/h1//text()` . Double slash will find all descents of node, not necessarily children

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the [`string` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256133.aspx).

```
string(/html/body/h1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Every node selected by an XPath expression has a corresponding string value. From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value):

> The string-value of an element node is the concatenation of the
>   string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in
>   document order.

Which is exactly what you want. This string value is often used implicitly, but you can *explicitly* retrieve it with the `string` function. Again, [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions):

> The string function converts an object to a string as follows:
>
> - A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of
>     the node in the node-set that is first in document order. If the
>     node-set is empty, an empty string is returned.

Use it like this:

```
string(/html/body/h1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to write : `'/html/body/h1'`. What you select with the `text()` function is the text nodes that are children of `h1` (`xyz` is not).

Comment: Yes I know I can get the whole h1 element (with the html tags) if I do that. My question is how do I get to `This is a xyz test` (without the html tags) using XPath without doing any further manual processing myself.